# How input argument to require command (bash)?

Tags: bash, gitlab-ci, pipeline, gitlab-ci-runner

I am writing pipeline script (gitlab CI/CD).

A bit of my script

```
  script:
    - npm install
    - b4a configure accountkey
```

But command **b4a configure accountkey** require input key

[image: Part doc of CLI b4a]

I know that is trivial question, but really I don't know how write my script (I have pure knowledge of bash).

I tried something **b4a configure accountkey | $BACKAPP** or - **b4a configure accountkey | read -s $BACKAPP** but it didn't work for me.

I couldn't find answer now I can input my arg to the command. Sorry for so stupid question :(

Comment: I do not know b4a at all, but what if you echo the key and pipe to the command? `echo keynumber|b4a configure accountkey`?

Comment: If the underlying shell in the gitlab-ci image is bash, an alternative way to send some text to the standard input of b4a, without using `echo`, is using a [here string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Here_strings): `b4a configure accountkey <<<"$BACKAPP"`, but beware that the `<<<` symbol might conflict with the YAML syntax, so you could quote the command: `- 'b4a configure accountkey <<<"$BACKAPP"'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you Gerhard and ErikMD!

Both options work for me!

```
echo keynumber|b4a configure accountkey

'b4a configure accountkey <<<"$BACKAPP"'
```

Comment: Fine! and feel free to accept your own answer then to mark it as "resolved" :)

Comment: But note that by `echo keynumber` you probably meant `echo "$BACKAPP" | …`, otherwise (obviously) the key would be hard-coded/committed in the Git repository… :)

Comment: Cool. But `echo $BACKAPP` instead as already mentioned by @EricMD. the comment I posted was just for you to test that the command does in fact accept stdin.

Comment: ErikMD, I can accept my answer only in two days. Yes, I understand replace `echo keynumber` to `echo "$BACKAPP"` :)